# Device uuid on iOS (phonegap)

Tags: ios, cordova, uuid

I have the following code:

```
function onLoad() 
{
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
}
function onDeviceReady() 
{
   var uuid = device.uuid;
   alert(uuid);
}
```

what am I doing wrong? Android operating normally.

From what I observed ios , is skipping the event **deviceready**

**I'm using PGB, and my config.xml it's ok*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deviceready code looks good to me, but I would suggest you drop the onLoad() function and just call that directly when the script loads.

For example, I created this using the Cordova demo app and it's working well on iOS simulator:

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, true);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        alert(device.uuid);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Comment: For I use the initialize, I'll have to use the phonegap cli or is not an obligation?

Comment: Should work fine with PhoneGap Build, which should run any JavaScript.